# Encode and submit a form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get, urlencode

I am submitting a form automatically on certain events using JavaScript. However, the URL is currently not encoded when submitted and is causing me some problems. For example, this is a submitted form's URL:

http://localhost/index.php?param=testParam%2Ftest.xml

I want to encode the URL and eliminate the %2F (Also, while we are at it, what does %2F means? I found what %2 means but what about the %2F?)

I have the following simple jQuery code:

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

How can I use this code and submitting the form with the URL encoded?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing a simple PHP script that will generate the url and redirect accordingly. Here is the code:

```
$url = $_GET['file'] . "?source=" . $_GET['source'];
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Using the header redirect, the URL is sent automatically in good decoded format.

Comment: It's not the header() redirect that sends it in "good encoded format". PHP automatically urldecodes data in $_GET. If you were to dump $url, you'd find that it already is urldecoded.

Answer (score 0):

`%2F` is the [url-encoded form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for '/'

you MUST urlencode special chars when you pass them to your server because it could be badly interpreted by http servers.

The server handle the decoding

Comment: I am saving the source where the page is to redirect in a hidden form. I tried encoding the value of the hidden element but it is still not being encoded

Comment: It must be. The browser does it automatically when you use the submit method. I suspect you are misinterpreting the symptoms.